# Confused with threading - Handler blocks UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a time consuming task (iterating through files and sending it's content to server)  that I want to execute in background thread, in specific interwal (that's why I want to use Handler).

From UI thread I have a call like this:

```
LogsManager lm;
lm = new LogsManager(this);
lm.processLogFiles();
```

And in `LogsManager` class I have following piece of code:

```
public void processLogFiles(){
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(logsRunable, 1000);    
}

private Runnable logsRunable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+Constants.LOG_DIR);             
            File[] logFiles = f.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < logFiles.length; i++) {
                readLogs(logFiles[i]); // executes some other methods inside
            }
        }
    };
```

As you can see it's just method with `Handler` that calls `Runnable`. And, unfortunately it also blocks my UI thread. Isn't `Handler` supposed to start a new thread for `Runnable`? I use handlers in other parts of my app also, and they works just fine. Am I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), `Handler`:

> When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it

So if you're creating `mHandler` in UI thread, then it will run the tasks in UI thread - hence the problem.

Comment: So, basically I have to create thread with runnable for Handler?

Comment: @Sver I think you don't actually need `Handler`. You can create a single thread or better use http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html to do the work

Comment: Thank you! ScheduledExecutorService works fine, and is easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

All the post* methods in Handler run code on Handler's original thread (in your case the GUI thread). If you want a background thread, you need to explicitly start one (see below) or use AsyncTask, if you need to update the GUI.

```
Thread t = new Thread(logsRunable);
t.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class for this purpose.

Scheduled the execution for the task after a specific delay, in your case it is 1000.

Comment: Because your UI thread will be hanged unless it finishes the time consuming background task

Answer (score 0):

I also think AsyncTask is a good solution for your case.